# Javascript Arrays-Counting up to create dynamic arrays in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, console.log

So I'm attempting to dynamically `console.log()` some arrays. My code is as follows:

```
var arr = []
var arr2 = []
data.forEach((data) => {
    arr.push(data.Name);
    arr2.push(data.Category);
}); 
let i = 1;
console.log([
  ['Name', 'Percentage'],
  ["'" + arr[i++] + "'", arr2[i++]]
]);
```

My original code was:

```
var arr = []
    var arr2 = []
    data.forEach((data) => {
        arr.push(data.Name);
        arr2.push(data.Category);
    }); 
    console.log([
          ['Name', 'Percentage'],
          ["'" + arr[0] + "'", arr2[0]],
          ["'" + arr[1] + "'", arr2[1]],
          ["'" + arr[2] + "'", arr2[2]]
    ]);
```

But I'm trying to find a method of making thousands of data sets.

Is there anyone out there who can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Any reason not to use a loop?

Comment: Consider using different names for different things. `data.forEach((data) => ...)` makes for some mental gymnastics you probably don't need. Just use `data.forEach((item) => ...)` instead. You could also simplify by just doing `console.table(data)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, `arr` and `arr2` will contain as much data as `data` provides. And that all you're doing is creating an array of arrays (possibly for a CSV or table) from `Name` and `Category` properties of the stuff in `data`. You can use `array.map()` instead:

```
// Creates an array of [Name,Category] items
const arr = data.map(d => [d.Name, d.Category])
const arrWithHeaders = [['Name', 'Percentage'], ...arr]

console.log(arrWithHeaders)
```